# View Power On Self Test (POST) details on Cisco 1841 Routers and Cisco 2950 switches

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I need to view POST details on Cisco 1841 Routers and Cisco 2950 switches.

I have tried `show post` and `show diagnostics post`. However, both these commands are not available.

What is the command that needs to be used?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What specific trouble are you trying to diagnose with this information?  I'm not easily finding a way to retroactively view the detailed POST info on the 1800 routers.  I'm going to try a 2950 shortly, but I have no great hope for that either.  If you can tell us the specific issue you're trying to diagnose, we may be able to offer other helpful solutions/suggestions.

Comment: @BrettLykins Thanks for looking into this. I am not trying to diagnose any particular issue. We were asked to view the POST details for these devices as a part of a university assignment. However, we are not able to find any commands for this. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`show post` should work on the Catalyst 2950, maybe you need to upgrade to a newer version of IOS?
Even if it works, it won't display more than "Pass" or "Fail".

For the 1841, I don't think there is a command to show post information.

> For Cisco IOS, the equivalent command is show diagnostic which was
>   introduced in 12.1(11b)E for the Catalyst 6000 series and show
>   diagnostics(with an s) which was introduced in for the Catalyst 4000
>   Series. Both commands display Power-On Self Test (POST) results. For
>   Cisco IOS on the 2900/3500XL, **2950/2955**, 3550, 2970 and 3750 series
>   switches, the **equivalent command is show post** which displays the
>   results of the switch POST.
>
> Note: For Catalyst 3750, 3550, 2970 , 2950/2955, and 2900/3500XL
>   Series switches use the show post command, which indicates **a simple
>   pass or fail for the hw status**. Use the LEDs on these switches to help
>   you understand the POST results.

Comment: I was trying this in Packet Tracer. Maybe thats what caused it not to work. However, this is really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

"show diagnostic post"
should work on the switch, not sure about 1841.